# heterogeneous comparisons in python3

Tags: python, comparison

I'm 99+% still using python 2.x, but I'm trying to think ahead to the day when I switch.

So, I know that using comparison operators (less/greater than, or equal to) on heterogeneous types that don't have a natural ordering is no longer supported in python3.x -- instead of some consistent (but arbitrary) result we raise `TypeError` instead. I see the logic in that, and even mostly think its a good thing. Consistency and refusing to guess is a virtue.

But what if you essentially want the python2.x behavior? What's the best way to go about getting it?

For fun (more or less) I was recently implementing a [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), a data structure that keeps its elements sorted. I wanted to use heterogeneous types as keys in the data structure, and I've got to compare keys to one another as I walk the data structure. The python2.x way of comparing makes this really convenient -- you get an understandable ordering amongst elements that have a natural ordering, and *some* ordering amongst those that don't.

Consistently using a sort/comparison key like `(type(obj).__name__, obj)` has the disadvantage of not interleaving the objects that do have a natural ordering; you get all your `float`s clustered together before your `int`s, and your `str`-derived class separates from your `str`s.

I came up with the following:

```
import operator

def hetero_sort_key(obj):
    cls = type(obj)
    return (cls.__name__+'_'+cls.__module__, obj)

def make_hetero_comparitor(fn):
    def comparator(a, b):
        try:
            return fn(a, b)
        except TypeError:
            return fn(hetero_sort_key(a), hetero_sort_key(b))
    return comparator

hetero_lt = make_hetero_comparitor(operator.lt)
hetero_gt = make_hetero_comparitor(operator.gt)
hetero_le = make_hetero_comparitor(operator.le)
hetero_ge = make_hetero_comparitor(operator.gt)
```

Is there a better way?

I suspect one could construct a corner case that this would screw up -- a situation where you can compare type A to B and type A to C, but where B and C raise `TypeError` when compared, and you can end up with something illogical like `a > b`, `a < c`, and yet `b > c` (because of how their class names sorted). I don't know how likely it is that you'd run into this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "fixing" something the python 3.x community "fixed" in the global scope, you may try the approach of enabling your objects/types to sort properly.  I'm not as familiar with python 3.x, but I'm sure there still is a `__cmp__` method that you could override in a sub-class and fix so that comparisons would work.  You could use that in combination with `id()` to restore the old broken behavior (which just sorted based on position in memory, `id()`, if my memory serves me correctly).